# How I have to add new header name in the given data frame with old header converted into first row in pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

This is the current data frame formed by 'pd.read_clipboard()' command, df(say)

```
    1   Sun TV      989709
0   2   Zee TV      704522
1   3   Zee Anmol   693027
2   4   STAR Plus   647026
3   5   Colors      614528
4   6   STAR Maa    603792
5   7   Rishtey     596039
6   8   Sony Pal    538710
7   9   Sony MAX    529383
8   10  Gemini TV   515458
```

I wanted like this

```
    Rank Channel    Rating
0   1   Sun TV      989709
1   2   Zee TV      704522
2   3   Zee Anmol   693027
3   4   STAR Plus   647026
4   5   Colors      614528
5   6   STAR Maa    603792
6   7   Rishtey     596039
7   8   Sony Pal    538710
8   9   Sony MAX    529383
9   10  Gemini TV   515458
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  :

```
pd.read_clipboard(...,names = [ "RANK", "cHANNEL", "Ratings"])
```

or:

```
df.columns =["RANK", "cHANNEL", "Ratings"]
```